# How do I scrape text from <a> links?

Tags: scrapy

How do I scrape text from `<a>` elements? For example:

```html
<div id="job_14" class="job">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.indeed.com/viewjob?t=Associate+Network+System&amp;c=Las+Vegas+Valley+Water+District&amp;l=Las+Vegas%2C+NV&amp;jk=a22e9d1fa81cae52&amp;indpubnum=4385896808151888&amp;atk=&amp;chnl=JobrollSearch" class="jobtitle" rel="nofollow">Associate Network
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with css selector:

```
response.css('.job a::text')
```

Which translates to select node with class `job` -> select child node `<a>` -> select current node's `text` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with xpath. CSS selector is translated to xpath and then executed.

```
my_xpath = "//div[@id='job_14']/a"
my_text = tree.xpath(my_xpath)
my_text = my_text.text
```